# Finding the positive solutions to the system $x\sqrt[3]{yzt}=1$, $y\sqrt[3]{xzt}=4$, $z\sqrt[3]{xyt}=9$, $t\sqrt[3]{xyz}=16$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Given the following system, how can I find all the positive solutions:
$\begin{cases}x\sqrt[3]{yzt}=1 \\[6pt] y\sqrt[3]{xzt}=4\\[6pt] z\sqrt[3]{xyt}=9\\[6pt] t\sqrt[3]{xyz}=16\end{cases}$.

I do not really know where to start with this one. I was thinking of multiplying every equation, but I don't think that will lead me anywhere: $(xyzt)^2 = 1\cdot 4 \cdot 9 \cdot 16 \iff xyzt = 1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4=24$. An idea I had was to now divide this with each equation getting to $\frac{xyzt}{x\sqrt[3]{yzt}} = \frac{24}{1} \iff \sqrt[3]{(yzt)^2}=24$, and so on for the other, but I the get stuck.

Any hints on how to start?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your work. Because, indeed multiplication *leads* to the solution.

Comment: Note that there are three factors with $x$ inside the root sign. The same for the others.

Comment: @lonestudent I added my try to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*NOTE*: $(xyzt)^2 = 1 \cdot 4 \cdot 9 \cdot 16$. Hence $xyzt = 24$ and now it's easy to get to eliminate any variables, except $x$ (for example).

Comment: I get it now, thank you! Instead of eliminating three variables at once by raising equations to $3$, I tried to eliminate only one variable which obviously doesn't help. But I just calculated everything and managed to reach the right answers with this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Good start !

Then notice that :

$$\begin{align}\begin{cases}x^3yzt=1\\ xyzt=24\end{cases}&\implies \frac{x^3yzt}{xyzt}=\frac {1}{24}\\
&\implies x^2=\frac {1}{24}\\
&\implies x=\frac {\sqrt 6}{12},\thinspace x>0\thinspace .\end{align}$$

Other variables are obtained in a similar way.

Comment: We assume that, the downvote is *not* about mathematical content.